# Trying to write code that simulates an action that is done within a program - python

Tags: python

I'm using an application on windows called Maestro that has a built in python shell. I'm creating a script that runs a certain number of times before it ends. Most packages are already built into the python shell but there are some that are not. What I am trying to do is make the program execute one action from the python shell. There is a source code for the program I'm using.
This is the link:

https://content.schrodinger.com/Docs/r2022-1/python_api/_modules/schrodinger/trajectory/trajectory_gui_dir/playertoolbar.html

I linked this because I believe it's within here.

To explain some more, inside the program there is a button that when you click it, it changes to the next frame in the simulation. Basically I need to simulate that happening in the python shell. The action itself is, going from one trajectory frame to the next one in the sequence. I'm thinking that it's `takeTrajectoryStep()` or maybe `updateCurrentFrame()`. I see that these things are under a class and are defined. I'm not sure how I would use them to execute this action, but this is what I have tried.

```
from schrodinger.trajectory.trajectory_gui_dir.playertoolbar import TrajectoryPlayer
TrajectoryPlayer.takeTrajectoryStep()
```

This return this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b4f42bd5075c> in <module>
      1 from schrodinger.trajectory.trajectory_gui_dir.playertoolbar import TrajectoryPlayer
----> 2 TrajectoryPlayer.takeTrajectoryStep()

TypeError: takeTrajectoryStep() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'curr_frame'
```

I think that it is able to pull the package correctly because when I have `TrajectoryPlayer.takeTrajectoryStep(` it displays some information about it. If it helps the program is called Maestro. Maestro pulls a Desmond file that contains information on a trajectory. A trajectory is basically a simulation of how a molecule reacts and contains a bunch of frames. A frame is one instance from the trajectory.

I am very new at coding. I think that I'm very close. I have everything else figured out with the script and it's been exciting to learn. I have been trying to figure this one problem out for a few days now and can't seem to make any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: problem with `self` suggests you have to first create instance - `player = TrajectoryPlayer()` and later use `player.takeTrajectoryStep(...)`.

Comment: I did this and ended up getting an AttributeError is there some way to get past this?

Comment: if you have new error then you should create new question on new page and put all new details.

Comment: when you run `TrajectoryPlayer()` then it runs `TrajectoryPlayer.__init__()` and in your link you can see what it needs `def __init__(self, trj_hub=None, matsci_profile=False, parent=None):`. And in the same link you can see what you need for `def takeTrajectoryStep(self, curr_frame):`